# Windows App Certification Failed Universal Windows App 10

Tags: javascript, html, uwp, winjs, windows-10-universal

I have developed a windows 10 universal app using Html,css and JS. For allowing inline scripts i am using ms-appx-web context and has set ms-appx-web:///login.html as start page in manifest.

I have added ApplicationContentUriRules in manifest file.

`<uap:ApplicationContentUriRules> 
<uap:Rule Match="ms-appx-web:///" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" /> </uap:ApplicationContentUriRules>`

When I tried to create app package for my app in release mode, Windows App Certification Kit - Test Results shows **Overall result: FAILED**.

I am allowing microphone, video library and Internet access to app.

[image: Here is the result]

My app needs access to internet, microphone and video library. How can I resolve this issue and create my app package successfully using Certification Kit?

and it shows this error also:
[image: Here is the result]

How can I handle app prelaunch without using WinJS Library?

Comment: The error message is clear. I'm afraid there is no way to workaround this.

Comment: How can I handle app prelaunch without using WinJS Library?

Comment: Then how I will submit my app to store?

Comment: Do not use `<uap:Rule Match="ms-appx-web:///" Type="include" WindowsRuntimeAccess="all" /> ` and change your inline js codes to js file.

Comment: For prelaunch problem, I think you can publish it to Store anyway if the previous problem is resolved. Please see [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569023/app-certification-fails-because-of-prelaunch-test).

Comment: Do I also have to remove `onclick="fun();"` from tags?

Comment: Yes, exactly. you need to remove it from html and attach the event in JS codes.

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT I need you help [Hosted api Issue in windows 10 universal app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39607881/hosted-api-issue-in-windows-10-universal-app)