# Hosted api Issue in windows 10 universal app

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, uwp

Hi I have created a windows universal app in which I am using API which is hosted on my machine's IP address. As I run the app whether from VS15 or from App package it works fine. But as soon as I run this app on another machine using app package it doesn't work.
Similarly if I host the same API on another machine's IP address it stops working on my machine.
Even though in both cases I can access the data via hitting the URL path in browser. 
But running the app package on phone works fine.

```
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x2efd, Could not complete the operation due to error 00002efd.
```

It shows this error.

Here is my ajax call sample:

```
var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
            url: apiAddress + "Conversation/Welcome"
        });
        ajaxRequest.done(function (response, textStatus) {
            if (textStatus == 'success') {
                //success
            } else {
                //fail
            }
        });
```

My webapiconfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes, configuration and services
            config.EnableCors();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        }
```

I have put `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` above the class.

Please help me. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Private Network Access was not allowed in Manifest. As soon as I have allowed that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Private Network Access was not allowed in Manifest. As soon as I have allowed that it worked fine.