# UWP App Certification Launchactivatedeventargs.Prelaunch

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp, app-certification-kit

I'm trying to test my UWP application for submitting it to the store with Microsoft App Certification Kit. The only problem I have is:

> in the onlaunched method implementation of the app, ensure you handle the launchactivatedeventargs.prelaunch option to be prelaunch event aware

I've never changed it, I'm using the original project from Visual Studio

```
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
    /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
    /// </summary>
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Suspending += OnSuspending;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when the application is launched normally by the end user.  Other entry points
    /// will be used such as when the application is launched to open a specific file.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the launch request and process.</param>
    protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e) {
    #if DEBUG
        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) {
            this.DebugSettings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
        }
    #endif
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
        // just ensure that the window is active
        if (rootFrame == null) {
            // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
            rootFrame = new Frame();

            rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

            if (e.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated) {
                //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
            }

            // Place the frame in the current Window
            Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
        }

        if (!e.PrelaunchActivated) {
            if (rootFrame.Content == null) {
                // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                // parameter
                rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(FormView), e.Arguments);
            }

            // Ensure the current window is active
            Window.Current.Activate();
        }

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when Navigation to a certain page fails
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The Frame which failed navigation</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the navigation failure</param>
    void OnNavigationFailed(object sender, NavigationFailedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Failed to load Page " + e.SourcePageType.FullName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Invoked when application execution is being suspended.  Application state is saved
    /// without knowing whether the application will be terminated or resumed with the contents
    /// of memory still intact.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender">The source of the suspend request.</param>
    /// <param name="e">Details about the suspend request.</param>
    private void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();
        //TODO: Save application state and stop any background activity
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

I googled a bit but everyone's speaking about a Template10 for UWP such al from this link 
[App Certification fails because of PreLaunch Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35569023/app-certification-fails-because-of-prelaunch-test)

Any suggestions? Thank you!
[image: Microsoft App Certification Kit Failed Result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a way to pass WACK. Sometimes the package can also passed the store certification even though it failed WACK before.

When you test your project under project property in the Build section, and then you checked **“Compile with .NET tool chain”,** it mean that you run your project in “Release” mode.by default your app utilizes the .NET Native toolchain. Since the package is compiled to native binaries, the package does not need to contain the .NET framework libraries. In addition, the package is dependent on the latest installed .NET Native runtime as opposed to the CoreCLR package. The .NET Native runtime on the device will always be compatible with your application package.
Local native compilation via the “Release” configuration will enable testing your application in an environment that is similar to what your customers will experience. **It is important to test this on a regular basis as you proceed with development.**

Because store will test the package that you submitting in .NET Native mode, you will passed the certification by checking **“Compile with .NET tool chain”.**

In addition, here is [an article](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/08/20/net-native-what-it-means-for-universal-windows-platform-uwp-developers/#7ZolbD92iPBxxXVU.97) about .NET Native, you could refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution but maybe it's just a lucky coincidence.

If under *Project Property* in the *Build* section, I checked "**Compile with.NET Native tool chain**" and now the result is **Passed**

[image: Visual Studio 2015 > Project Property]

Do you think it's the right answer?